# How to use ContextMenu with Grid in Vaadin Flow?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

When using Vaadin Flow (11.0.0) it should be possible to use `Grid` with `ContextMenu` (1.0.0). See issue https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-context-menu-flow/issues/5.

This is what I have so far:

```
@Route("menu")
public class MenuTestView extends VerticalLayout {

    public MenuTestView() {
        final Grid<String> g = new Grid<>();
        g.setWidth("20em");
        g.addColumn(s -> s).setHeader("Word");
        g.addColumn(s -> s.length()).setHeader("Length");
        g.setItems("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".split("\\s+"));

        final Label label = new Label();

        final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        contextMenu.setTarget(g);

        contextMenu.addItem("Item 1", e -> label.setText(e.getSource().getText()));
        contextMenu.addItem("Item 2", e -> label.setText(e.getSource().getText()));

        add(g, label);
    }

}
```

Questions:

- Is there any example for Vaadin **Flow**?
- In our use-case the `ContextMenu` should only be enabled if hovered over a selected row. How to achieve this?
- How to select a row, based on the mouse position at the moment the context menu is activated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vaadin-grid-flow 1.2 brought specifically support to make Grid and context menu play nice together. It was released three days ago. It is possible to make them work together before, but the event didn’t tell which item the context menu was triggered on. See https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid-flow/releases/tag/1.2.0

You can upgrade your grid to 1.2 by adding the following to the pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-grid-flow</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here’s example usage from the tests: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid-flow/blob/master/src/test/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/it/ContextMenuGridPage.java

```
    GridContextMenu<Person> contextMenu = grid.addContextMenu();
    contextMenu.addItem("Show name of context menu target item", e -> {
        String name = e.getItem().map(Person::getName)
                .orElse("no target item");
        message.setText(name);
    });
```

Comment: Great! The remaining issue is that from UX perspective it would be nice to select the row before the menu choice is made, so when the menu pops up. This is not supported afaik?

Comment: Do you mean that the right click would both select the row and open the context menu for it? I don't think that case is supported.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Because otherwise, it could confuse the user if a row is already selected and the mouse is located at another row